# Why is the component.scss style not applied but the all.scss?

Tags: css, angular, sass, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a component with a .scss file where I want to define the styles for the component. (what a surprise)
A minimal working example can be found here: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9dzgyd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.scss,src%2Fstyles.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

If I define the style for the Switch in the app.scss it has no effect, but when doing the same in the styles.scss it all works fine.

Can someone elaborate on this a bit further and maybe explain a way on how to achieve the goal of beeing able to define component-related styles in the component.scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the [Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation).

Every component has its own scope of code that applies to itself. For example, a very stupid one, you can have two components with the same function with the same name that do different things without any problem. The same rule applies to `styles`.

The reason why styiling or overriding things such as external libraries (Kendo, Material, etc) is usually done at `root level` is because you put the code in one place and it's valid across all the application. (IE: in the `styles.scss` file, that gets loaded at runtime).

If you want to do that override in your component, you can use `Encapsulation.None` in the component's decorator. Be aware that by doing that, all the styles defined in the component will be available to every components in your application, and you keep your component's code clean.

Comment: I actually read the article partly before writing the question. I think I just dont grasp what is written there the ways it is meant. What I understand is, that by default the ViewEncapsulation is emulated (emulating ShadowDom). By that the styles are encapsulated to the component they are written in - e.g. ap.scss as in my example.
But why are they not applied then? I guess they are overwritten by Kendo, right? how to achieve, that the style of my app.scss is prefered over the kendo style or the global style (if there is any defined falsly) without ViewEncapsulation:None?

Comment: The encapsulation is for the component's scope; the styles defined at root level have nothing to do with encapsulation. Said that, using `!important` I believe is the only way possibile, since the libraries styles are loaded after the general styles

Comment: but as you can see in my stackblitz example even with `!important` the style is not applied on component level, but doing the same on root level even without `!important` the style is applied to the component. I don't get why it works this way.

Comment: As I said, is because of encapsulation.  The `!important` can vary due to the library. Besides, the Stacakblitz wont load to me sadly so I can't really test it out. But I'm using Material in a work project and every override we make, we're doing it at root level. In some cases we're doing it at the component level, simply by adding the rules and using  none as encapsulation.

Comment: Besides, I prefer to put the override style in a separated scss file at root level to keep the code as clean as possibile.

Comment: ok in the end its the framework making trouble. Since Kendo sets specific variables in the case of a switch, it is required to overwrite them at root level. besides there documentation beeing deprecated. see (all the way down at the bottom) : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/inputs/switch/labels/